# Reading a text file that contains special character delimiters, then concatenating portions of the read file as a string and pushing it to a vector

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, getline

I'm reading a text file that was converted from excel.  There's all sorts of funky spacing issues. I'm using the getline function to grab the whole line, which I can do, my issue is the \v character, I need to use that as a sentinel and concatenate the strings to make one long string (it's a name), then an associated student ID, and then course Number.  I'm kinda at a loss of ideas, any insight or suggestions would be appreciated

```
    while (iFile.fail())
    {
cout << "Error. File doesn't exit." << endl;

userInput = requestFileName();
iFile.open(userInput.c_str());
    }


while (getline(iFile, userInput))
{

    cout << userInput << endl;

}

iFile.close();
```

Comment: [A `getline` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) allows you to swap \v for \n. load the line into a `stringstream`, then parse the `stringstream` with something like `getline(linestream, token, '\n')`

Comment: @user4581301 is it possible that I read each getline and then have a a for loop inside the while loop to read character by character and prep my concatenated string of information for a vector push?

Comment: That's a roger. `for(char ch: userInput)` will do that. Just noticed a typio in my last comment: `getline(linestream, token, '\n')` should have been `getline(linestream, token, '\v')`